# Remove duplicate words from a string in golang

Tags: go

i have a string in golang :

"hi hi hi ho ho hello"

I would like to remove duplicates word to keep only one to obtain this :

"hi ho hello"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple way to achive this. One is this:

```golang
import "strings"

func Dedup(input string) string {
    unique := []string{}

    words := strings.Split(input, " ")
    for _, word := range words {
        // If we alredy have this word, skip.
        if contains(unique, word) {
            continue
        }
 
        unique = append(unique, word)
    }
 
    return strings.Join(unique, " ")
}
 
func contains(strs []string, str string) bool {
    for _, s := range strs {
        if s == str {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: `Dedup("high hi hi hi ho ho hello")` removes all instances of "hi" ([run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U8CtwlLjna7)).

Comment: user462794 look at the edited code, the post was incorrect as @MuffinTop commented.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main
import "fmt"

func removeDuplicates(arr []string) []string {
    words_string := map[string]bool{}
    for i:= range arr {
        words_string[arr[i]] = true
    }
    desired_output := []string{}  // Keep all keys from the map into a slice.
    for j, _ := range words_string {
        desired_output = append(desired_output, j)
    }
    return desired_output
}
func main() {
    arr := []string{"hi", "hi", "hi", "ho", "ho", "hello"}
    fmt.Println(arr)
    desired_output := removeDuplicates(arr)  // Remove the duplicates
    fmt.Println(desired_output)
}
```

Comment: Here only one issue, I can see related to order of retrieval. While fetching the final results, it does not maintain the order.